# Dynamically Insert Input Fields when doing Localisation | AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, localization, bind

Am trying to implement localisation in my App. The english version looks like this:
[English Localisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3v1t.png)
"My age is _____ and I would like to invest in Equity"

The requirement is when I translate it in chinese/or any other language the position of input field may change as well.

So lets in chinese version it may be like "________ (Chinese Equivalent of) My age is and I would like to invest in Equity"

I used following code for localization              http://plnkr.co/edit/NAaJ9v6kULqtuE0Vk2p4?p=preview

```
{  
"COLOR" : "Farge",
"HELLO" : "Hallo",
"HELLO_WORLD" : "Hallo verden!"
}
```

So how can I extend it to change the position of the input element when localising it.